# How to apply long's L when using variable names in Java?

Tags: java, factorial

I've tried to build a factorial generator out of words, but every time I enter some big numbers, it makes my numbers negative.

I figured I should use a `long` with an identifier (`L`). I've applied it to the initialization of the `long`, but that didn't fix it. I guess the problem is somewhere around here:

```
for (int j = 1 ; j <= wordLength; j++) {
    temp *=  j;
}
```

how do I assign the `L` to `temp` so it reserves enough space for the number to fit in?

Comment: what is the exact error message? what is temp? What is wordLength value?

Comment: Factorial gets big really quickly. Consider using BigInteger instead: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `l` isn't applied to variable-names. You can of course do that to include the type of a variable in it's name, but that's rather a question of style than anything else, like this:

```
long avariableL = someLong;

for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    avariableL *= i;
```

`l` is only used for constants in the code, like

```
long someLong = 123456789L;
```

Variables don't magically change their type during execution of code. You'll have to declare the variable as long.

Comment: Alright, but I did that, I declared my variable as following:    long temp = 1L;

Comment: @Bribri probably you simply used a too large value. `long` only expands the range roughly to the square of the range of `int`. And factorials grow quite fast. `21!` already exceeds the limitations of `long´. If you want to use larger numbers, you'll have to switch to `BigInteger`.

Comment: Thanks Ill look into it!